How to pass component as props in vue 3 composition api?
i want to pass props customActionComponent as component and need to render in child component
FlightDetail.vue
<template>
  <ComponentCard
    title="Flight Details"
    subtitle="March 25th"
    :tableComponent="FlightDetailTable"
    :actionComponent="customActionComponent"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import ComponentCard from '@/components/ComponentCard.vue'
import FlightDetailTable from '@/components/FlightDetailTable.vue'

const customActionComponent = {
  template: `
      <v-row align="center">
      <v-col>
        <v-btn class="rounded-pill ml-3 custom-button">
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="d-flex justify-end">
        <v-btn class="rounded-pill custom-button">
          Flight
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn class="rounded-pill ml-4 mr-4 custom-button">
          Delay
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>`,
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.custom-button {
  background-color: #114b5f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

ComponentCard.vue
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  title: String,
  subtitle: String,
  tableComponent: Object,
  actionComponent:Object,
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-card variant="text">
    <v-card-item>
      <v-card-title style="color: #114b5f;">{{  props.title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle style="color: #114b5f;">{{ props.subtitle }}</v-card-subtitle>
    </v-card-item>
    <v-card-text>
      <component :is="props.tableComponent" />
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions v-if="props.actionComponent">
      <component :is="props.actionComponent" />
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>


tableComponent can render successfully but can't visible actionComponent.
what is the best way to define customActionComponent and pass as props in child component

This could be interesting for you https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements#component

Can be XY problem. In vue this is solved with slots rather than props. It's unknown why customActionComponent is defined as a variable. This requires to use vue runtime that supports template compilation in order to use template strings.

Instead of passing the whole component as props you can pass the component name and leverage it in the child component with defineAsyncComponent
eg:
Inside the script tag add this
 const components = {
  Table: defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/components/Table.vue")),
  UserForm: defineAsyncComponent(() => 
  import("@/components/UserForm.vue")),
 };

 const componentResolver = ref<any>();

 // Now based on the component passed you can choose
 componentResolver.value = components[props.component];

 // Now in the template you can have this
 <Component
       :is="componentResolver"
     />


I would definitely use named slots here. I don't see why you would want to do this with props.

customActionComponent is a component object that hasn't been compiled by Vue. If you want to let it work, replace https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js with https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm.js in your import map to include a compiler. This may bring a larger size to your app.
If possible, it is recommended to use slots.
